# asp.net tree view upto 15 levels in web page

Tags: asp.net

I wont to show three level hierarchy**(Means parent have 3 childs and these childs should have again 3 childs for each)** upto 15 levels in asp web page. but this is very difficult to show in page because the no.of images increases upto thousends. so what is the best way to show to users upto 15 levels.

Regards and Thanks
Hareesh

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this jquery control which allow you get child runtime**
http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: I got some confusion in your solution. can you provide me a clear explanation. actually iam doin multi trade service project. so users should have ability to see their position in entire page